# IntelliJ IDEA: json file syntax

Tags: javascript, json, intellij-idea, syntax-error

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 for a web project, where I want to keep a file `a.js` containing a JSON object. The content of the `a.js` is

```
{
    "ac" : "abc",
    "d" : 4,
    "_constants": {}
}
```

While editing this file, IntelliJ keeps reminding me that this file has syntactic errors. It makes a hints after "ac", "d" and "_constants", before the semicolon, saying "Expecting newline or semicolon".

Does not IntelliJ IDEA accept a file containing a JSON object as a legitimate javascript file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ has a separate file type for JSON files. It will be applied if you rename your file from a.js to a.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can add file pattern to your settings

Settings->Editor->File Types->Json

For example "json-config-*.js"